# Cant find solution for angularx-social-login with LinkedIn login Support

Tags: angular

I try to implement angular 10 application with linkedin login. But it can't support this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here I have provided a sample code for linked in login in angular for your reference.
App.module.ts 
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { MyChannelComponent } from './my-channel/my-channel.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MyChannelComponent
  
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'client id'
            )
          },
           {
            id: LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new LinkedinLoginProvider("1098828800522-m2ig6bieilc3tpqvmlcpdvrpvn86q4ks.apps.googleusercontent.com")
          },
        ]
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Auth.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { GoogleLoginProvider, SocialAuthService, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { YoutubeService } from '../youtube.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  public socialUser!: SocialUser;
  public username:any;
  isLoggedin: boolean=false;
  subscription:any; 

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService,private service:YoutubeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });    
    
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.socialUser = user;
      this.username=this.socialUser.firstName;
      this.isLoggedin = (user != null);
      console.log(this.socialUser);
      //this.GetChannel(this.username);
    });
  }

 
  loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }
loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signOut();
  }


}
```

Comment: In app.module.ts file, '"angularx-social-login"' has no exported member 'LinkedinLoginProvider'. How it will be solved?